# How to remove "Powered By" in Jetty 9.2.x

Tags: java, jetty

I'm trying to implement a custom errorhandler and with a jetty-web.xml in /webapp/WEB-INF and it's working fine.

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
   <Set name="errorHandler">
      <New class="com.example.CustomErrorHandler" />
   </Set>
</Configure>
```

But I need to place this handler inside the /etc/jetty.xml to make it available to the entire server. I tried it like mentioned in the doku: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/custom-error-pages.html

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
...
  <Call name="addBean">
    <Arg>
      <New class="com.example.CustomErrorHandler"/>
    </Arg>
  </Call> 
</Configure>
```

This throws no errors and the server is working fine but the default errorhandler instead the custom handler handles the errorpages.

This is the custom errorhandler :

```
public class CustomErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

   public CustomErrorHandler() {
      super.setShowMessageInTitle(false);
      super.setShowStacks(false);
   }

   @Override
   protected void writeErrorPageBody(final HttpServletRequest request, final Writer writer, final int code,
         final String message, final boolean showStacks) throws IOException {
      final String uri = request.getRequestURI();

      writeErrorPageMessage(request, writer, code, message, uri);
      if (showStacks) {
         writeErrorPageStacks(request, writer);
      }
   }
}
```

So why is the custom handler not aktivated in the jetty.xml?

Edit: using jetty 9.2.19.v20160908

Comment: I see mention of `jetty-web.xml` and `/webapp/WEB-INF`, is this for an actual WAR / WebApp? or something else?

Comment: Also, what is your end goal, what are you trying to achieve? (a custom `ErrorHandler` is usually for those that want to manage non-context errors, which is the opposite of your efforts to use it via `jetty-web.xml`)

Comment: My goal is to remove the "Powered by Jetty" from the default error pages.

Comment: yes the jetty-web.xml calls the jar with the cutsom error handler and give it to the context handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note: Jetty 9.2.x is EOL (End of Life) - Use a newer supported / stable version of Jetty.
>   https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html

There exists a configuration to remove the `Powered by Jetty` from default error pages (and also the `Server` header from the HTTP Response headers).

This is the `HttpConfiguration.setSendServerVersion(false)` setting.

No need to create a custom `ErrorHandler` or anything that complicated.

The `HttpConfiguration` lives within the `ServerConnector` that is setup to bind to a port and accept your incoming connections.

If you are using a proper `${jetty.base}` directory with your `${jetty.home}` ([as documented](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup-base-and-home.html)), then you can use a property to configure this setting for all `ServerConnector` configurations that `${jetty.home}` ships with  ...

An example.

Lets setup a simple `${jetty.base}` which is enough to demonstrate.

```
[tmp]$ mkdir noprovided-base
[tmp]$ cd noprovided-base/
[noprovided-base]$ java -jar ~/jetty-home-9.4.22.v20191022/start.jar \
  --create-startd \
  --add-to-start=http,deploy,webapp
MKDIR : ${jetty.base}/start.d
INFO  : webapp          initialized in ${jetty.base}/start.d/webapp.ini
INFO  : server          transitively enabled, ini template available with --add-to-start=server
INFO  : security        transitively enabled
INFO  : servlet         transitively enabled
INFO  : http            initialized in ${jetty.base}/start.d/http.ini
INFO  : threadpool      transitively enabled, ini template available with --add-to-start=threadpool
INFO  : bytebufferpool  transitively enabled, ini template available with --add-to-start=bytebufferpool
INFO  : deploy          initialized in ${jetty.base}/start.d/deploy.ini
MKDIR : ${jetty.base}/webapps
INFO  : Base directory was modified

[noprovided-base]$ ls -la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 joakim joakim 4096 Nov 13 08:09 ./
drwxr-xr-x 13 joakim joakim 4096 Nov 13 08:08 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 joakim joakim 4096 Nov 13 08:09 start.d/
drwxr-xr-x  2 joakim joakim 4096 Nov 13 08:09 webapps/
```

Now lets run this essentially default / unconfigured `${jetty.base}`

```
[noprovided-base]$ java -jar ~/jetty-home-9.4.22.v20191022/start.jar
2019-11-13 08:12:28.248:INFO::main: Logging initialized @379ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2019-11-13 08:12:28.467:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.22.v20191022; built: 2019-10-22T13:37:13.455Z; git: b1e6b55512e008f7fbdf1cbea4ff8a6446d1073b; jvm 11.0.5+10
2019-11-13 08:12:28.480:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///home/joakim/tmp/noprovided-base/webapps/] at interval 1
2019-11-13 08:12:28.503:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@48ebde5e{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2019-11-13 08:12:28.504:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @634ms
```

And see what kind of error message (and response headers) it produces ...

```
[tmp]$ curl -vvvv http://localhost:8080/flarg
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /flarg HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 442
< Server: Jetty(9.4.22.v20191022)
< 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/flarg</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>404</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Not Found</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>-</td></tr>
</table>
<hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.22.v20191022</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

Yup, the `Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.22.v20191022` response body footer and `Server: Jetty(9.4.22.v20191022)` header are present.

Now lets configure this `${jetty.base}` to disable the version reporting.

```
[noprovided-base]$ echo "jetty.httpConfig.sendServerVersion=false" >> start.ini
[noprovided-base]$ cat start.ini 
jetty.httpConfig.sendServerVersion=false
```

One restart of the Server and another test shows ...

```
[tmp]$ curl -vvvv http://localhost:8080/flarg
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /flarg HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 357
< 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/flarg</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>404</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Not Found</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>-</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The `Powered by` response body footer and `Server` response header are now gone.

In your version of Jetty (9.2.18.v20160721), the "Powered by Jetty" is present in 5 different places (`ContextHandler`, `DefaultHandler`, `HttpSpiContextHandler`, `Response`, and finally `ErrorHandler`).  If you are using a standalone Jetty server, then 4 are always present.

It is not possible to remove all of these references with your old version of Jetty.

This was addressed over multiple commits on the Jetty 9.3.0 codebase.

The final commit was [eclipse/jetty.project@64287189](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/6428718962b26ece54736da897ac9755eda265e2)

You must use Jetty 9.3.0 (or newer) to be able to remove those references from the kinds of responses that Jetty produces.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I tried this in the etc/jetty.xml:

<New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
       ...
      <Set name="sendServerVersion">false</Set>
      <Set name="sendDateHeader">false</Set>
   </New>

But it still doesn't work and the "powered by jetty" is shown.

Comment: Did you upgrade your version of Jetty?

Comment: Since you are making changes to not show the version of Jetty, presumably for some kind of security audit.  You should know that Jetty `9.2.19.v20160908` is vulnerable to multiple CVEs.  You need to upgrade to satisfy any legitimate security audit.

Comment: no an update is unfortunately  not possible at the momment. Isn't it possible to fix this "powered by jetty" with my current version?

Comment: If your goal is to remove "Powered by" from automatically generated Jetty responses (headers and body), then you must update, as there are more places that can generate that "Powered by" then just `ErrorHandler`, and those other places cannot be overridden with custom code.  See updated answer.